# Multiple classes in a file but order matters when calling them

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm making the design choice of having an enum and class in the same file. The class has existed for a while, but I have just added the enum for the first time.

```
namespace App\Models;

enum ProcessType: string
{
  //...
}

class Process extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
  //...
}
```

If I call the ProcessType enum, I get an error, `Class "App\Models\ProcessType" not found`

```
// This code produces an error
dump(ProcessType::AGENT_UPLOAD);
dump(Process::query());
```

However, If I use the Process class first in the code, there is no error and the enum works as intended.

```
// This code is okay
dump(Process::query());
dump(ProcessType::AGENT_UPLOAD);
```

I have tried running `composer dump-autoload` because I thought it might have something to do with the class mapping, but that didn't help. All I want to do is call the `ProcessType` enum independently of the `Process` class.

Comment: Bad design choice (you will have autoload problems, also it goes against Psr4 standard, which you might wanna follow). First case is not working because there is no file name that corresponds to the class name. Second one is working because the file is already loaded. Have the two in separate files to avoid this type of problems.

Comment: It's a bad design choice, and fundamentally broken without additional work to indicate where `ProcessType` should be autoloaded from. Abandon this ill-conceived scheme, and just put `ProcessType` on its own file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll put them in separate files then